# text with \n and unicode literals saved in mysql do not work when displayed

Tags: flutter

I store a text string with \n and unicode literals like \u2022 in mysql, then retrieve it with http api call on flutter. When displaying it with Text widget, these escaped symbles do not show as expected. When I directly pass the string , it works. Could anyone help me out?

```
child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
    Text(prompt.prompt_body, //This variable is from http call which does not work
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        style:TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 13,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic

        )),
    Divider(),
    Text("You live in a room in college which you share with another student.However, there are many problems with this arrangement and you find it very difficult to work.\n\nWrite a letter to the accommodation officer at the college. In the letter,\n\n   \u2022 describe the situation\n   \u2022 explain your problems and why it is difficult to work\n   \u2022 say what kind of accommodation you would prefer",  //this part works
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        style:TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 13,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic

        ))
    ],
  ),
```

[emulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71GCi.png)

In response to Gunter's query, I add the following code on api call:

```
     class PromptModel {
     int id;
     String prompt_body;
     String prompt_image;

      PromptModel(this.id, this.prompt_body, this.prompt_image);

       PromptModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
      id = parsedJson['id'];
      prompt_body = parsedJson['prompt_body'];
       prompt_image = parsedJson['prompt_image'];
    }
    }

  ....

 class PromptListPageState extends State<PromptListPage> {
  int counter = 0;
  List<PromptModel> prompts = [];

  void fetchImage() async {
    counter++;
    var response =
    await get('http://10.0.2.2:8080/TestPrompt');
    var promptModel = PromptModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));

    setState(() {
      prompts.add(promptModel);
    });
  }
```

The following is the response of the api call:

```
{"id":1,"prompt_body":"You live in a room in college which you share with another student.However, there are many problems with this arrangement and you find it very difficult to work.\\n\\nWrite a letter to the accommodation officer at the college. In the letter,\\n\\n   \\u2022 describe the situation\\n   \\u2022 explain your problems and why it is difficult to work\\n   \\u2022 say what kind of accommodation you would prefer","prompt_image":"http://10.0.2.2:8080/test.jpg"}
```

Comment: That's probably a mistake when you create the MySQL entries where the unicode literals are not actually created as unicode literals but as string that looks like an unicode literal. We'd need to see the code where you do that to be able to point out the mistake.

Comment: Gunter, thank you for the quick response. I add some info in the question regarding your query. Please  help to take a look.

Comment: The problem is in the rrsponse `\\u2022` should be `\u2022`

Comment: Hi Gunter, many thanks for the finding. It seems quite tricky saving unicode literals in mysql. I will do some study on this part. Thanks again.

Comment: So the problem is solved?

Comment: Not yet. Will update the thread with the progress.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by inputting the string from flutter using TextFormField. directly inserting the text on database side is tricky. The code is as below:

```
Widget build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  controller: myController,
                  maxLines: 5,
                  validator: (val) =>
                      (val == null || val.isEmpty) ? "请输入商品名称" : null,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    //icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                    hintText: 'add the prompt here：',
                    labelText: 'Prompt content',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal)),
                  ),
                  onSaved: (val) => this.content = val,
                ),
                new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  child: new RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: _save,
                    child: new Text('Save'),
                  ),
                )
              ]),
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Add Essay Prompt'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```